# Why after using Garbage collector, free memory became decrease than early ? Runtime.getRuntime().gc() in Java

Tags: java, runtime

I m learning Java with book Java The Complete Reference  Eleventh Edition.  I saw that example and compare results. I can not explain why the results are various from each other. My Java version is 13.
My English level is bad and I wrote that text with translate. Sorry, if you do not understand.

```
public class baseClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime gfg = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long memory1, memory2;
    Integer integer[] = new Integer[1000];

    // checking the total memeory
    System.out.println("Total memory is: "
            + gfg.totalMemory());

    // checking free memory
    memory1 = gfg.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Initial free memory: "
            + memory1);

    // calling the garbage collector on demand
    gfg.gc();

    memory1 = gfg.freeMemory();

    System.out.println("Free memory after garbage "
            + "collection: " + memory1);

    // allocating integers
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        integer[i] = new Integer(i);

    memory2 = gfg.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Free memory after allocation: "
            + memory2);

    System.out.println("Memeory used by allocation: " +
            (memory1 - memory2));

    // discard integers
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        integer[i] = null;

    gfg.gc();

    memory2 = gfg.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Free memeory after  "
            + "collecting discarded Integers: " + memory2);
}
```

Comment: Result Total memory is: 100663296
Initial free memory: 98270456
Free memory after garbage collection: 7515736
Free memory after allocation: 7431728
Memeory used by allocation: 84008
Free memeory after  collecting discarded Integers: 7514880

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information to it. It's hard to read them inside the comments.

Comment: `gc()` is just a suggestion that garbage collection is performed, not that it is actually done synchronously at that point.   All the other setting and clearing plays into it.  Essentially you can't trust `gc()`